# Magento 2 Search - how to show result when customer search for a SKU with prefix and suffix? EX: AA-SKU1234

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, search-criteria, search-terms

Is there a way to return result for `'SKU`', if the customer search for the term like `'AA-SKU2033'`?

Currently, our product has the following format on the actual product sticker `'AA-SKU2033'`

```
'AA-' is the prefix, and it's always the same.
'SKU' is the actual SKU on magento 2 website
'2033' is a four digit numbers for lot number purpose, for example year of 2020 and week of 33, and it changes overtime.
```

Is there a way for magento to handle that? or is there a recommended search extension can be configured to work with it?

I'm currently on magento 2.2.9
Thanks.

Comment: first you should ensure that the sku attribute is enabled for search. depending on your search engine mysql/elasticsearch the hyphen (-) can be treated as a space which increases false positives in search. you can improve the results using search synonyms configurable in admin,

Comment: hi paj, thank you for the advise. yes the sku attribute is enabled. my concern is, for example, my sku number is BAG, but if the customer search for AA-BAG1234, i would like it to return result of 'BAG'. in here, 'AA-' is the prefix, and '1234' is suffix and can be any number. Right now, if search for AA-BAG, it does return the result of 'BAG', i think the tricky part is how to handle those 4 digits in the suffix? thanks